# Repetitive code in ASP.NET MVC Controller with use of Unity of Work class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

according to [this ASP.NET MVC article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) I created a Unity of Work class in combination with a generic repository.

I have a lot of model classes as well as always the same controller actions like Create, Update, Delete and so on. So in each controller, the Create action would look like

```
      public ActionResult Create(
      [Bind(Include = "CourseID,Title,Credits,DepartmentID")]
     Course course)
  {
     try
     {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           unitOfWork.CourseRepository.Insert(course);
           unitOfWork.Save();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
     }
     catch (DataException)
     {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
     }
     return View(course);
  }
```

So my question is: is it possible to create e.g. a "global" ActionResult "Create" in a BaseController, where the right UoW Repository is used according to the entity (or give over the relevant repository of Unity of work class)?

In the specific controller action, I would only like to call this global method like:

```
return new BaseController().Create(entity)
```

Answer (score 0):

usually BaseController is an abstract class, and should not be possible to make an instance out of it. I think you should run the Create from specific Controller like this below:

```
return new CourseController(new CourseRepository()).Create(course);
```

BaseController should implement a interface like IRepository.Create, and while initialization of specific controller you could pass the right repository - maybe with a help of IoC you could just request CourseController with all Dependencies Injected.

I hope this helps.